# Twitter Regex to extract user

Tags: regex, twitter

my script returns the twitter username in this format: `https://twitter.com/fegtoken?s=09`

I've tried this regex and it get's me close but the `s=09` is still there.
`[^https:\/\/twitter\.com\/]([a-zA-Z])+(\?)`. any suggestions?

I'd like the regex to extract just the username `fegtoken`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [twitter help center](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-username-rules) for username restrictions you can use this to get username: `(?<=https:\/\/twitter\.com\/)\w{1,15}`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fTXgSs/2)

Answer (score 1):

A few notes about the pattern that you tried:

- In this part `([a-zA-Z])+` you should repeat the character class itself inside the capture group like `([a-zA-Z]+)` or else repeating a capture group itself would return the value of the last iteration, being an `n` char
- This part `[^https:\/\/twitter\.com\/]` denotes a character class, you should omit the outer square brackets
- Note that this part `(\?)` captures the question mark, so there will only be a match if it is present

If the question mark should be present, you can match it (or omit the question mark if it should not be present)

The value is in capture group 1.

```
^https:\/\/twitter\.com\/([a-zA-Z]+)\?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wp86lg/1)

Depending on the pattern delimiters, you don't have to escape the backslash

```
^https://twitter\.com/([a-zA-Z]+)\?
```

Comment: Hi, Twitter username can contain numbers and underscore. so i think `[a-zA-Z]` can replace with `\w`

Comment: @Alireza I have read that in your answer and that is correct :-) My answer is mainly about  why the match was not as expected.